# Fastest way to get the next element in a string from a needle

Tags: php, loops, math, ascii

I'll just start off with some code:

```
$characterset = 'abcdefg';
$character    = 'a';
```

Say I have two variables, `characterset` and `character`, and I want to get the next `character`, so I did:

```
$characterset = 'abcdefg';
$character    = 'a';
$ncharacter   = $characterset[ strpos($characterset, $character) + 1 ];
```

And that worked, but I'm using a method that has to do this thousands of times `per / second`, and using `XDebug + WebGrind` the result was many, many calls to `strpos`, making the function go a lot slower than it should be going, I realise doing `math` in a language is faster than doing function calls to do the math, and I have tried using:

```
$character  = 'a';
$ncharacter = chr( ord($character) + 1 );
```

And that would work, but that gives me too many characters and if I wanted to make sure that it didn't `+1` to a character like a `:` or etc, it'd be a bunch of conditional arguments, making it slower, so what I am looking for is a cheap way to `character -> nextcharacter (determined from characterset)` that doesn't use a lot of resources, benchmarks from `WebGrind` are preferred.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Let me know if my solution worked. If not then what is the problem with it.

Comment: @RyanVincent but that gives me a bunch of unwanted characters in the charset, and removes the charset entirely, I see the relation with the characters :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
# The character set that we're using to iterate.
$CharacterSet  = 'abcdefg';
$chr_array = str_split($CharacterSet);

foreach($chr_array as $Character){
//do whatever with character, everytime it will provide the next one when foreach loop continues
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply! I'm working for multiple at the same time so I was just off doing the other, I'll try your method now :-)

Comment: I don't think this is the exact way I wanted to do the call, replace a `strpos` with a `split` + `foreach iteration` in a `20000` time loop, if that makes sense? I want to be able to have a really clean and cheap way to get the character next to the current character in the array selected. If I have `a`, and the `charset = abc`, I'd get `b` back.